# Put Subcaptions on the right of vertically aligned subfigures

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, subfig

I'm struggling to find a solution for my problem. I want something like this [image]

but for VERTICALLY aligned subfigures, as an attempt to save some vertical space (I can't reduce the size more than this)

I'm using `\subfig` package  to have my subfigures aligned. here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]

        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[]
            {
                \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{fig_a}
                \label{fig:a}
            }
        \\
        \centering
            \subfloat[]
            {
                \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{fig_b}
                \label{fig:b}
            }
            \\
            \centering
            \subfloat[]
            {
                \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{fig_c}
                \label{fig:c}
            }
            \caption{Three figures, take too much vertical space}
            \label{fig:unified}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

Thank you for any help!
[image: Basically I want this]

Comment: As I pointed out, I can't reduce the size, otherwise labels in the image are not readable once printed. Plus, your comment is in no way a solution to my answer!

Comment: @koleygr Wouldn't that be horizontal alignment instead of vertical?

Comment: @Fed How do your subcaptions look like? Are that only one-letter-captions or may they need e.g. line breaking (if they are longer than the remaining space)?

Comment: @TeXnician... You are right... I just read fast the post and thought that got the point... Deleting... Fed.. sorry!

Comment: @TeXnician Ideally they would be two or three words names (like "Logistic regression", "Naive Bayes" etc), but I'm also ok with letters like in the pictures, then I can explain to which algorithm they correspond in the "general" caption

Comment: Actually, you could probably get it to fit with vertical subcaptions just by changing [ht!] to [p].

Comment: @Fed, I have a method but it is without `subcaption` nor `subfig` and it needs the caption placed at the top (for now)... If you want I can add it... Or I am going to finish it with bottom ability too and share it later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that only the image is centered, not the caption.

Ideally one should put the `\label` immediately after the `\caption`, but in this case that isn't possible.  Instead one should put the `\label` inside the caption.  Otherwise some of the local macros used by `\label` may be lost.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{showframe}% debuggingh tool

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysub}[2][]% #1=caption (optional), #2=graphics
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#2}\usebox0
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0\relax
  \ifx\\\@centercr \divide\dimen0 by 2\fi
  \sbox1{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimen0}
    \subcaption{#1}%
  \end{minipage}}%
  \rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht0-\ht1}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox1}}\allowbreak
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
            \centering
            \mysub[A very long caption, just to test the limits. \label{fig:a}]
            {\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}

            \mysub[\label{fig:b}]
            {\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}

            \mysub[\label{fig:c}]
            {\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}}

            \caption{Three figures, take too much vertical space}
            \label{fig:unified}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```